# How to execute the next line after getting response from http client in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular13

Without getting response from  const thumbnailSource = this.getThumbnailImage(); next line get excecuted, after getting response from getThumbnailImage() have to execute next line

```
constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
const defaultThumbnail: File[] = [];
const defaultArticle: File[] = [];

createArticle(articleData: IArticleData, thumbnail?: File | string, articleImage?: File | string) {
    const defaultThumbnail: File[] = [];
    const defaultArticle: File[] = [];

    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('title', articleData.title);
    formData.append('author', articleData.author);
    formData.append('articleData', articleData.articleData);
    formData.append('published', JSON.stringify(articleData.published));

    if (thumbnail) {
      formData.append('thumbnail', thumbnail);
    }

    if (articleImage) {
      formData.append('articleImage', articleImage);
    }

    if (!thumbnail) {
      const thumbnailSource = this.getThumbnailImage();
      thumbnailSource.subscribe((res) => {
        defaultThumbnail.push(res);
      });

      formData.append('thumbnail', defaultThumail);
    }

    if (!articleImage) {
      const articleSource = this.getArticleImage();
      articleSource.subscribe((res) => {
        defaultArticle.push(res);
      });

       formData.append('articleImage',defaultArticle);
    }
    formData.forEach((value, key) => {
      console.log(key + ' ' + value);
    });
    return this.httpClient.post<IAPIResponse<IArticleCollection[]>>(`${baseUrl}/article/`, formData);
  }



getThumbnailImage() {
    return this.httpClient
      .get('assets/images/logos/logo.png', {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      })
      .pipe(
        map((response: any) => {
          return new File([response], 'thumbnail-default.png', { type: 'image/png' });
        }),
      );
  }

 getArticleImage() {
    return this.httpClient
      .get('assets/images/logos/logo.png', {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      })
      .pipe(
        map((response: any) => {
          return new File([response], 'article-default.png', { type: 'image/png' });
        }),
      );
  }
```

Comment: put the line **inside** subscribe function

Comment: formdata has no scope inside it

Comment: where are you defined the formData? you're using flat arrow, should be share the scope.

Comment: Your problem is that you want return an observable that depend (or nor) of anothers observables, use forkjoin and switchmap rxjs operators better than use promises, wait and async,(see the answer)

Answer (score 1):

You return an observable that can depend of two observables or not, so you can use the Rxjs operators

1. of: return an objservable of a value, e.g. of(1) return an
   Observable
2. forkJoin: return an observable compouned from others observables
3. switchmap: transform an observable in another observable (it's used
   when the "inner" observable depend from the outer observable

```
    //you create two observables
    const thumbnailSource = thumbnail? of(thumbnail):this.getThumbnailImage();
    const articleSource = articleImage? of (articleImage) : this.getArticleImage();
    
    //you create an unique observable using forkJoin
    return forkJoin([thumbnailSource,articleSource]).pipe(
         switchMap(([thumbnail,articleImage])=>
         {
            const formData = new FormData();
    
            formData.append('title', articleData.title);
            formData.append('author', articleData.author);
            formData.append('articleData', articleData.articleData);
            formData.append('published', JSON.stringify(articleData.published));
    
            formData.append('thumbnail', thumbnail);
            formData.append('articleImage',articleImage);
            return this.httpClient.post<IAPIResponse<IArticleCollection[]>>
                 (`${baseUrl}/article/`, formData);
         }
    ))
```

BTW, is unneccesary use formData, you can use a simple object

```
return forkJoin([thumbnailSource,articleSource]).pipe(
     switchMap(([thumbnail,articleImage])=>
     {
        const data={
              'title', articleData.title,
              'author', articleData.author,
              'articleData', articleData.articleData,
              'published', JSON.stringify(articleData.published),
              'thumbnail', thumbnail,
              'articleImage',articleImage
        }
        return this.httpClient.post<IAPIResponse<IArticleCollection[]>>
             (`${baseUrl}/article/`, data);
     }
))
```

Comment: first answer worked correctly. Thanks for the answer @Eliseo